# determine if a method has already been called GetValue .net

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, system.reflection, propertyinfo

Is there a .net method that determines whether or not a given method has been previously called for a given object instance?

Sometimes a property getter method has side effects.  For instance, a property getter if not called previously may need to create additional objects and perform other work in order to return the value of a backing field.  I can't have that happen.  If the getter method hasn't been called previously, I don't need the value.

For example...

```
object item = something;
foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfoForItem in item.GetProperties(Reflection.BindingFlags.Public)) {
  //Need something to avoid calling this if the property getter method has not been previously been called for this item
  object itemPropertyValue = nothing;
  itemPropertyValue = propertyInfoForItem.GetValue(item, null);
}
```

I've looked through the MethodInfo class returned from PropertyInfo.GetGetMethod() and didn't spot anything there that would help.

Any ideas?

As an additional note based on feedback (and thanks for chiming in!), I wouldn't be able to modify the existing objects I'm inspecting.

Comment: you can set up a counter in the object itself. I don't think there is such a method you are looking for.

Comment: having a property getter that suddenly start creating extra object or other tasks isn't such a good design I would say... Why not make sure that your property getters only provide a value and uses the INotifyPropertyChanged interface to indicate that something happened?

Comment: btw, maybe an Interceptor could help at this place, just this would depend heavily on your used framework (IOC?)

Comment: Thanks all for the feedback.  Unfortunately I don't have the luxury of modifying the existing objects.

Answer (score 4):

I think your way of achieving this goal is overly complicated. You can simply use a `bool` or numeric class-level variable for this purpose.

```
public class C
{
    private int _counter = 0;
    // private bool _methodCalled = false;

    public void M()
    {
        // check the state of _counter or _methodCalled

        _counter++;
        // _methodCalled = true;
    }
}
```

You can make the private variable `static` if you want to take all calls into account, regardless of the instance of the class that was used to invoke it.

Note that locking may be necessary if there is some multi-threading going on and you have conditional branching depending on the counter.

**EDIT**

Since the class cannot be modified (as stated in the comment), you'll need to create a wrapper class that will aggregate your class and hold the counter.

```
public class CWrapper
{
     private int _counter = 0;
     private C _c = new C();

     public M()
     {
         if (_counter == 0)
         {
             _c.M();
         }

         counter++;
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the class being inspected cannot be modified.  Sorry I didn't mention that originally.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've stated a few times that you do not have the ability to modify the objects in question, your only option is going to be to implement wrapper classes for those object types. In your wrapper class you can expose all of the properties and methods on the objects in question, but you can implement in your wrapper Getters the reference counting suggested in the other answers.

If you need to determine if a Getter has been called before you have access to the object, I'm afraid you are out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a static count within the class and then within the method for the first time increment to 1 if 0 and subsequent times if 1 then you know it has been called already and you can return -1 or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) design pattern in order to do it.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args) {
       var hasDoMethodInstance =  new HasDoMethodImpl();
       var hasDoMethodDecoratorInstance = new HasDoMethodDecorator(hasDoMethodInstance);

        hasDoMethodDecoratorInstance.Do();
    }
}

public interface IHasDoMethod
{
    void Do();
}

public class HasDoMethodDecorator : IHasDoMethod
{
    private int counter = 0;
    private readonly IHasDoMethod hasDoMethod;

    public HasDoMethodDecorator(IHasDoMethod hasDoMethod) {
        this.hasDoMethod = hasDoMethod;
    }

    public void Do() {
        hasDoMethod.Do();
        counter++;
    }
}

public class HasDoMethodImpl : IHasDoMethod
{
    public void Do() {
        //Your logic
    }
}
```